# Bit operator AND & Bit shift

Tags: c#, binary, console, bit-shift, and-operator

Helllo guys,
right of the bat I should probably say that i started coding like a year ago, so im not experienced in the itty bitty details (and more) of coding and.... stuff. I should add that Im currently coding in c# in a console, too. Also the variables are partly in Czech, if youre wondering. Oh right, the code.

I want to create a program that would calculate you the VLSM. And that means Im working with bit and shift operators. In the code you get to the point, where you have to use AND operator (which I found to be "&").
The problem is that it only does AND operation ONCE, then it stops, and I have no idea why.
Code:

```
// IP[jednicky] - the IP number in the array its changing. The "jednicky" (Ones in english) 
// are a little bit complicated, but in short it knows which of the IP´s to change.
// BinarniKontroler - variable, which stores ones in a sequence (Ex: 1110 0000)

IP[jednicky] = BinarniKontroler >> 1 & RawIP;

Console.WriteLine($"{BinarniKontroler >> 1} & {BinarniKontrolovany} AND - {IP[jednicky]}");

Console.WriteLine($"{IP[0]}.{IP[1]}.{IP[2]}.{IP[3]}");    
Console.ReadLine();
```

The second, lesser problem is that my calculations are a bit incorrect, and the binary number (which is in Int32) "BinarniKontroler" has an extra zero at the end. I could improve (maybe) improve the code, but... yeah. I planned to just use a bit shift ">>". The good news is that it actually shifts the binary number to the right, but it changes all the ones into 5??? (Ex: 1110 0000 -> 555 0000), and i have no clue why that is. But I think it doesnt hurt the AND operation, so whatev.
PS: You can probably tell Im totally new to Stack overflow, so tell me if you need more info, etc.

Comment: If you need the whole code (which you probably want now that I think about it), its here (warning, spaghetti code, and whole lots of not used variables coming): https://shrib.com/#Elise5zZe242

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but operator precedence means your code is effectively `(BinarniKontroler >> 1) & RawIP`, so I think you should be putting brackets like so `BinarniKontroler >> (1 & RawIP)`

Comment: Which `&` is executed only once? And why do you expect it to run more?

Comment: I would suggest that you write a small application for you to investigate how C# bitwise operations work and how the ( ) symbols affect your evaluations in C# first.

Comment: To answer the comments: 1) I know how operator precedence works. I see how you would come to that conclusion, but the way I want is "(BK (for short) >> 1) & RawIP" .  2) I... dont understand? I think the "&" which is executed is the only "&" there..? (If youre refering to the code I added to the comments, then I understand the confusion, but Im equally confused as you xd) 3) I did that, and it did the same thing, like exactly whats here, so idk.